# Alternative to LibreOffice Base for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there a database management software for Ubuntu alternative to LibreOffice Base?

LObase works fine for a while, but occasionally the files I'm working on get corrupted and I lose all my work.

Comment: The only consideration I would mention is that LO Base is a front-end tool for the database of your choice. It has a default db that it will use if you do not provide it with a database to use. I have to wonder if your corruption issue is due to the database engine, and might be addressed by switching databases, not the front-end (Base). Example - switch to MySQL as your back end. I can't say I know this is your problem - but it is a thought.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try **Kexi**.

> Kexi is an open source visual database creator, a long-awaited competitor for programs like MS Access or Filemaker.

It is part of the [Calligra Suite](http://www.calligra.org) (but can be used completely independently).

To install from the software center:

## [Kexi](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kexi) [image: Install Kexi]

From the command line:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal.
- When it opens, run the following command:

  ```
   sudo apt-get install kexi
  ```

For more information, or to download Kexi, see [the Kexi website](http://www.kexi-project.org)

Comment: Kexi does look promising, however, there are problems importing data from MySql/CSV/ODS and the process terminates. Also, there doesn't seem to be any option to directly work on MySql database although it connects alright. Note: for MySql connection on localhost, uncheck the socket file based connection option on the details tab of add new connection.

Comment: The install link redirects to snapcraft.io, which in turn does not find "kexi". But I found it on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/kexi), so you can install it with `apt-get`.

Answer (score 4):

You can try **Glom**. It's a complete database system like FileMaker Pro (or Access).

> With Glom you can design table definitions and the relationships between them, plus arrange the fields on the screen. You can edit and search the data in those tables, and specify field values in terms of other fields. It's as easy as it should be. The design is loosely based on FileMaker Pro, with the added advantage of separation between interface and data. Its simple framework should be enough to implement most database applications. Without Glom these systems normally consist of lots of repetitive, unmaintainable code.

To install from the software center:

## [Glom](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/glom) [image: Install Glom]

From the command line:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal.
- When it opens, run the following command:

  ```
   sudo apt-get install glom
  ```

For more information, see the [Glom website](http://www.glom.org)

Answer (score 0):

Since the reason for looking for an alternative was data corruption, here's another option: use LibreOffice Base with a split-database configuration, instead of with the default embedded datatabase.

By default Base uses HSQLDB (v1.8) combined with the Base configuration in a zip file. This bundling of database structure and data with other settings makes the file [susceptible to data corruption](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=17567#p162653).

Instead, you can [convert](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=65980) existing databases to a split-database configuration, and/or start new projects with a split-database [wizard](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=61183) which uses HSQLDB (v2.3).

The split-database configuration requires macro functionality to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out about

**[TablePlus](https://tableplus.com/linux)**

The best one I found yet for connecting to a server and editing simple databases with a simple GUI.
Currently free for Linux (not floss tough).

Kexi is great too, but according to the FAQ, it cannot use an existing database because it needs to store metadata in the database also.