# Using NOT replacing MS Access in Ubuntu

Tags: 13.10

Is there an app for Ubuntu 13.10 that will allow Me to use a MS Access database? I do not want to convert it because some of the machines on this network are still running Windows. So I need to be able to access the Access file, edit it, use it and save it in native MS Access format from My Ubuntu machine. I am not familiar with the apps available.

Comment: Try Kexi.  Take a look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/303218/alternative-to-libreoffice-base-for-ubuntu

Comment: With current versions of Ubuntu you can use LibreOffice Base as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/519571/323236).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256459/populate-a-ms-access-database-in-linux). You'll find some interesting suggestions to your problem. Namely, you have the following options

- Use some proprietary ODBC driver
- Use a programming language specific library like jackcess (java) or MDB Tools (C) - Both are open source
- Use Crossover Office (optimized but not free) or install through Wine (free - assuming you have a valid license for office)
- Create a web user interface for your application and connect it to access via ASP/PHP/etc

For more details and links to the specific solutions follow the abovementioned link.

Also you may find it worthwhile to have a look at [Kexi](http://www.kexi-project.org/). AFAIK it has some limited .mdb tools.

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario **Playonlinux** comes to my mind. Visit http://www.playonlinux.com/en. This application will allow you to install MS Access 200X on your machine. -- Regards.